# How generate a matrix?

Tags: jquery, arrays, matrix

I want to generate a matrix from a given table.

But I dont know generate a variable that properly store the matrix.

Example table:

```
<table>     
    <tr class="csv-row">
        <td class="field-sort">Ashton Cox</td>
        <td class="field-sort">ashtoncox@gmail.com</td>
        <td class="field-sort">01/06/1995</td>
        <td class="field-sort">Visitante</td>
        <td class="field-sort">01/10/2014</td>
        <td class="field-sort">10/01/2014</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="csv-row">
        <td class="field-sort">Bruno Nash</td>
        <td class="field-sort">brunonash@hotmail.com.br</td>
        <td class="field-sort">10/06/1988</td>
        <td class="field-sort">Atacado</td>
        <td class="field-sort">01/10/2014</td>
        <td class="field-sort">10/01/2014</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

My loop:

```
jQuery('tr.csv-row').each(function() {
    jQuery(this).find('td.field-sort').each(function() {

    });
});
```

I want a variable that returns me an matrix like this:

```
Array[0]
(
    [0] => Ashton Cox
    [1] => ashtoncox@gmail.com
    [2] => 01/06/1995
    [3] => Visitante
    [4] => 01/10/2014
    [5] => 10/01/2014
),
Array[1]
(
    [0] => Bruno Nash
    [1] => brunonash@hotmail.com.br
    [2] => 10/06/1988
    [3] => Atacado
    [4] => 01/10/2014
    [5] => 10/01/2014
)
```

My example does not work correctly:

```
var jsonArr = [];
jQuery('tr.csv-row').each(function() {          
    jQuery(this).find('td.field-sort').each(function() {
        jsonArr.push({                  
            name: jQuery(this).text(),
            email: jQuery(this).text(),
            group: jQuery(this).text(),
            born: jQuery(this).text(),
            purchase: jQuery(this).text(),
            created: jQuery(this).text()
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want "two-dimensional" array, you can modify your code into this:

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q4oncqv9/1/).

```
var jsonArr = [];
jQuery('tr.csv-row').each(function(index)
{
    jsonArr[index] = [];
    jQuery(this).find('td.field-sort').each(function()
    {
        jsonArr[index].push(jQuery(this).text());
    });
});
console.log(jsonArr);
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this code.

```js
var jsonArr = [];
var jsonInnerArr = [];
    jQuery('tr.csv-row').each(function() {          
        jQuery(this).find('td.field-sort').each(function() {
            jsonInnerArr.push(jQuery(this).text());
        });
      jsonArr.push(jsonInnerArr);
      jsonInnerArr = [];
      
    });

console.log(jsonArr);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>     
        <tr class="csv-row">
            <td class="field-sort">Ashton Cox</td>
            <td class="field-sort">ashtoncox@gmail.com</td>
            <td class="field-sort">01/06/1995</td>
            <td class="field-sort">Visitante</td>
            <td class="field-sort">01/10/2014</td>
            <td class="field-sort">10/01/2014</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="csv-row">
            <td class="field-sort">Bruno Nash</td>
            <td class="field-sort">brunonash@hotmail.com.br</td>
            <td class="field-sort">10/06/1988</td>
            <td class="field-sort">Atacado</td>
            <td class="field-sort">01/10/2014</td>
            <td class="field-sort">10/01/2014</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: Well, let's just say that it is the same that I've posted.